# How to create Flutter Firebase Firestore ArrayList?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create an ArrayList in Firebase Firestore with Flutter. There will be no items in it. How can I do that?

```
users.doc(idToken).set({
   'email': _registerEmail.text,
   'name-surname': _registerNameSurname.text,
   'list': "ArrayList code" // ArrayList,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give an empty list as an argument:

```
users.doc(idToken).set({
   'email': _registerEmail.text,
   'name-surname': _registerNameSurname.text,
   'list': [],
});
```